# Multiline equation is not working

Tags: equations

I have a multiline equation as below:

```
\begin{equation}
l_{t i}\left(v_{t} j\right)=\left\{\begin{array}{ll} \\\
0 & \text { if } r_{j}=r_{i} \\\
1 & \text { if } r_{j}<r_{i} \\\
2 & \text { if } r_{j}>r_{i}
\end{equation}
```

but I get this error:

```
! You can't use `\eqno' in math mode.
\endmathdisplay@a ...\df@tag \@empty \else \veqno 
                                                  \alt@tag \df@tag \fi \ifx ...
l.264 \end{equation}
```

and when I move the line breaks, I get this instead:

```
! Extra alignment tab has been changed to \cr.
<recently read> \endtemplate 

l.262 1 &
          \text { if } r_{j}<r_{i}
?
```

I am not sure what is wrong.

Comment: Do you have blank lines in your real  equation?

Comment: oh wow thank, I didn't know the blank lines would affect the tag. However, I have another error now (will edit my original question)

Comment: A  blank line starts a new paragraph, and it is incompatible with math mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use the `cases` environment, like this, without any blank line:

```
\begin{equation}
l_{t i} (v_{t} j)=\begin{cases}  
0 & \text { if } r_{j}=r_{i} \\ 1 & \text { if } r_{j}r_{i}
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
```